# why I can't record javascript in automation of instruments when target is my pad(4.3.3)

Tags: iphone, instruments

I am a rookie to automation in instruments. I have been coping with this tough problem for several days, but nothing productive happen.
Here is the problem: when I begin to click the record btn below script window, what I get is "script capture is not available on this device" , and I can't go further because the record process comes to the end. any suggestion? I will definitely appreciate your helps.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded the iOS version which solved my problem.

If your project build settings supports 5.X versions and you have a device with iOS 4.x, when you try to record the script in Automation instrument, you will face the above problem.

Therefore upgrade your iOS to the version your project supports.